# Calculations involving dates and integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I am working on SQL Server and have been trying to solve this question. How many more years does each employee have to work before reaching sentiment, if sentiment age is 65?

```
SELECT 
    BusinessEntityID,  DATEDIFF (year, BirthDate, ModifiedDate) AS 'Age', DATEDIFF (year, 60, 'Age') AS 'Age to Sentient'
FROM
    HumanResources.Employee
```

I expected to have three columns of BusinessEntityID, Age and Age to Sentiment. But I keep getting this error message:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I have been able to solve it . I tried this and it worked SELECT 
 BusinessEntityID, 65 - (CAST(DATEDIFF (year, BirthDate, ModifiedDate)AS INT)) AS YTR
FROM
 HumanResources.Employee

Comment: How accurate do you want to be? `DATEDIFF(YEAR` merely measures the number of year boundaries (Jan 1) crossed between two dates. Dec 31 2022 -> Jan 1 2023 is the same as Jan 1 2022 -> Dec 31 2023 ([`DATEDIFF(YEAR) = 1` in both cases](https://dbfiddle.uk/1zBppaR_), even though most people will have no birthdays in the first range, and two birthdays in the latter range).

Comment: Whats a "sentiment age"?

Comment: In future please provide sample data and desired results and table definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge here is this statement: `DATEDIFF (year, 60, 'Age')`.  From an SQL Server Perspective, you are asking it to use the *string* 'Age', when it is expecting a date.

If you want the 3 columns alone, then try something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    BusinessEntityID, 
    DATEDIFF (year, BirthDate, ModifiedDate) AS 'Age', 
    65 - DATEDIFF (year, BirthDate, ModifiedDate) AS 'Years to Sentient' 
FROM 
    HumanResources.Employee
```

Of course, if the Employee is already over 65, then you will get a negative number, in which case, you might want to convert that negative number to a zero, for clarity, like so:

```
SELECT 
   BusinessEntityID, 
   DATEDIFF (year, BirthDate, ModifiedDate) AS 'Age', 
   (CASE 
       WHEN DATEDIFF (year, BirthDate, ModifiedDate) >= 65 
    THEN 
       0 
    ELSE 
       65 - DATEDIFF (year, BirthDate, ModifiedDate) 
    END) AS 'Years to Sentient' 
FROM 
    HumanResources.Employee
```